# Obtener imagen por ruta relativa c#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web en **C#** y quiero obtener la imagen "check.PNG" desde la `class Generador`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado con estas rutas pero me sale un error. Me indica que no encuentra el archivo.

```
string icheck = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "check.PNG";
//string icheck = "..\\..\\check.PNG";
//string icheck = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "check.PNG")
//string icheck = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName,"check.PNG";
```

Comment: Te recomendaría [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un poco más de información de contexto (Hay diferentes tipos de "Proyectos web", ej: AspNet, WebForms, MVC, AspNetCore, etc). Revisa este link: [repro] para que veas cómo se debería preguntar (también este: [ask]). Tampoco es muy claro a que te refieres con "obtener".

Comment: Puedes poner la estructura de carpetas que tienes?

Comment: Has intendado con  Server.MapPath("~/Utility/")+"check.PNG";

Comment: @EdgarVazquez si me sirvió, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo tal vez podrias intentar con

```
Server.MapPath("~/Utility/")+"check.PNG";
```

Lo que esto hace es que al poner el simbolo ~ indicamos que no importa donde este tu encuentralo y ya que lo encuentre se le concatena la imagen que estas buscando

Saludos